# Change text color of title-group CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML to show a group of data:

```
<!-- Content ================================================== -->
<div class="container margin_60_35">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="nomargin_top">Agenda</h3>
            @foreach($agenda['canchas'] as $cancha)
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="title-group" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Cancha {{ $cancha['idCancha'] }}</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @foreach($cancha['turnos'] as $turno)
                            <li class="list-group-item">{{ $turno['hora'] }} ({{ $turno['estado'] }})</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div><!-- End col-md-9 -->
    </div><!-- End row -->
</div><!-- End container -->
<!-- End Content =============================================== -->
```

**What I want is to change title color of the collapsable group.**

**CSS:**

```
.panel-title{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading{
    background-color: #3F51B5!important;
}
.list-group{
     color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

Y tried:

```
.panel-title{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

but not changed the color.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.panel-title{ }` is **not specific enough** since you're trying to target the inner `a` whose styles might be already defined.

**Try instead:**

```
.panel-title a {
   color: red;
}
```

by the same principle, if somewhere in CSS you already have a style like `h4 a{}` than you need to add again a higher specificity:

```
h4.panel-title a {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know about !important since you've used it in the panel-group class. Have you tried using it to change the color of your .panel-title class?

```
.panel-title {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` should be discouraged since there's almost always a way to properly write CSS - it should be used as a last resort only if it's use will not break further styling rule-sets.